# Is it possible to defer messages in OS X mail.app till later?

Tags: macos, mail.app, desktop

I want to hide messages until I can act on them. Outlook for iOS has an option of removing messages from inbox and moving them back at a specified time.
Basically if a new message comes in, I need to triage it. If it requires an immediate response I will do so, otherwise I want to "defer" it, but I dont want it to get lost.

Comment: Isn't that what the inbox is for - read and then immediately reply and move to a named folder or leave in inbox

Comment: Mark: No, the point is that the inbox ought to hold strictly items which need consideration. Having the system bring it back when it's useful to consider it is a nice simple way of keeping your workflow clean, because it means there's exactly one place to check.

Comment: @bmike, i hope it's clearer now. Outlook for iOS was referenced as an example of such functionality, but I'm looking for a solution to mail.app on desktop.

Comment: Yes - it's much +1 better. There should be lots of automation tips as well as  ways to use smart mailbox, flags, tags, whatever to snooze items and manage the display of messages. Sometimes we bend to software and other times it's better to make the software do the bending :-)